# Intent detection confidence

Tags: watson-assistant

The question relates to IBM Watson Assistant dialog management.

I have implemented a digression workflow that is triggered by a certain user intent. Unfortunatelly, the minimal confidence level when this intent is recognized is too low for my use case.

Is there a way to adjust/force certain confidence level with regards to specific intents?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this globally for the the top 10 intents that are returned by using

intent[0].confidence > 0.00

This will mean that you're node will only trigger if the confidence is above a certain threshold

or you can do a combination of the rule on your dialog node to make it more accurate. Specifying the [0] means that Watson will make sure that the highest scoring intent is above a certain threshold for confidence.

#Intent && intent[0].confidence > 0.99